# Unidentified Protocol murray on port 1123

Tags: port, nmap, port-scanning

I conducted a basic nmap scan of a box I have set up below is the output.

```
$ nmap xxx.xx.org

Starting Nmap 7.40SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-17 13:25 GMT
Nmap scan report for xxx.xx.xx (xx.xx.5.180)
Host is up (0.00069s latency).
rDNS record for xx.xx.5.180: www.xxx.org
Not shown: 988 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
20/tcp    closed ftp-data
21/tcp    open   ftp
53/tcp    open   domain
80/tcp    open   http
110/tcp   open   pop3
143/tcp   open   imap
443/tcp   open   https
993/tcp   open   imaps
995/tcp   open   pop3s
1123/tcp  open   murray
2030/tcp  open   device2
10000/tcp open   snet-sensor-mgmt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.94 seconds
```

what cought my interest was murray port, I dont seem to find what is that making that port open.

Answer (score 5):

That's me! I'm the author of murray. It was a webshots-like system, for windows and os/2 and I registered port 1123 for it.
Alas, you're probably not running murray, so it's some other program that just happens to be using that port.

```
sudo netstat -napt | grep 1123
```

and that will tell you what process is actually holding that port, and that might give you a clue as to what's really using it.

Answer (score 1):

The "murray" name comes from the [`nmap-services`](https://nmap.org/book/nmap-services.html) database of well-known port numbers and service names. It does not necessarily indicate what software is really using that port. For that, you need to either use [Nmap's service and application version detection](https://nmap.org/book/man-version-detection.html) (`-sV`) or use the [`netstat` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) on the target system directly to list the process that is using port 1123.